# React-admin how show notification about error from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

React-Admin: 2.9.5

i have next code

```
const CreateUserComponentBase = (props) => {
    const { ...rest } = props

    return (
        <SimpleForm
            validate={validate}
            {...rest}
        >
            {/*...code*/}
        </SimpleForm>
    )
}

const UserCreateBase = (props: any) => {
    const { setTitle, ...rest } = props

    return (
        <Create {...rest}>
            <CreateUserForm {...rest}  isEdit={false} />
        </Create>
    )
};
```

I am sending a request on server And my API generates an error message, and how do I output this message if React-Admin only "Server Error" shows it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know on v2.9.5 but in the latest version you can use `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks like so

```
const handleFailure = (error) => {
  notify(`Something bad happened: ${error}`), 'error');
};

const handleSuccess = (data) => {
  notify('Success!');
  redirect('show', props.basePath, data.id);
  refresh();
};

return (
  <Edit
    {...props}
    onFailure={handleFailure}
    onSuccess={handleSuccess}
  >
    ...
  </Edit>
);
```